# Mule HTTP parameter

Tags: http, service, mule

I created a service where you call the mule service via http:

```
<http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8086" path="idnum" doc:name="HTTP"/>
```

so if you want to call this service you type:

```
http://localhost:8086/idnum
```

but what i want is for the http to accept an id number as a parameter and then store the id number into a variable so that i can use the id number. So the http would look like:

```
http://localhost:8086/idnum/4583948364094 for example.
```

So my question is how do you get the parameter from the url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the id as a **message inbound parameter** as following .. In Mule flow you need to do the following :-

```
<flow name="test">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
                           host="localhost" port="8086"
                           path="idnum" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <!-- storing id in variable myId -->
    <set-variable variableName="myId"
                  value="#[message.inboundProperties['id']]" 
                  doc:name="Variable"/>
    <!-- Print the variable in console -->
    <logger level="INFO"  message="My id :- #[flowVars['myId']]"/>        
</flow>
```

Now in browser access

```
http://localhost:8086/idnum/?id=4583948364094
```

Now you can store it in a variable in Mule and you can see it in a logger like:

```
My id :- 4583948364094
```

Comment: Hi there, your reply is much appreciated. is there any possible way of having the url as: http://localhost:8086/idnum/4583948364094 and then just retrieving the 4583948364094 as a parameter. and then storing that id number to a flow var.

Comment: See .. The first thing is that,this is the way to put as a parameter as it will get stored in message inbound properties id (message header) .. if you use localhost:8086/idnum/4583948364094, the idnum/4583948364094 will me treated as message payload (message Body ) and you may get the value as idnum/4583948364094 instead of just 4583948364094 .. In that case you need to use #[message.payload] instead of #[message.inboundProperties['id']] .. and you may get the value in message.payload as idnum/4583948364094 .. so you need to perform some String function like substring() on message.payload ..

Answer (score 4):

From Mule-3.6 on wards, we have [HTTP Listener Connector](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/HTTP+Listener+Connector), using which you can pass URI parameters.

You can access the URI parameters using the below MEL

`#[message.inboundProperties.'http.uri.params'.id]` provided your URI should be like this: http://localhost:8086/idnum/{id}

Comment: And the URI parameters are now automatically set as `flowVars`, so you can access your `id` URI param simply using: `#[flowVars.id]`